# Fetch all unused assets?

Tags: assets, elementcriteriamodel

How could I go about fetching all assets that are not currently beeing used anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With good help from @carlcs here and on Slack, we found a solution:

```
{% set allEntryIds = craft.entries.limit(null).ids() %}

{% set usedAssets = craft.assets({
    relatedTo: allEntryIds,
    limit: null,
}).ids() %}
{% set unusedAssets = craft.assets({
    id: 'and, not ' ~ usedAssets|join(', not '),
    limit: null
}) %}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, this is for all assets not used by *entries only*, they could be used by other elements like craft commerce products.

Comment: Yes, and even other assets I discovered :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: This solution doesn't work, but no-one can explain why (maybe a Craft bug?). I'm leaving the code for reference though.

--

You could get them with a `craft.assets` element criteria model and a `relatedTo` param. Just pass a `'and, not 8, not 13, not 26'` type of string to `sourceElement`, with all element IDs listed that you want to exclude from an otherwise `limit: null` assets query.

```
{% set allEntryIds = craft.entries.limit(null).ids() %}
{% set allCategoryIds = craft.categories.limit(null).ids() %}

{% set omitIds = allEntryIds|merge([allCategoryIds]) %}
{% set idsParam = 'and, not ' ~ omitIds|join(', not ') %}

{% set unusedAssets = craft.assets({
    relatedTo: {
        sourceElement: idsParam,
    },
    limit: 0,
}) %}
```

Comment: I get an "Array to string conversion" error on the line where you join the omitIds, is there a way around that?